# Cancel a Tourist (C) visa issued for all schengen states

Tags: visas, schengen, cancellations

I'm the guarantee host for a tourist visa for my former girlfriend. Now she got the visa in her passport, but we just split. Is there a way to cancel the visa? She alread got the passport with the visa. Can the visa be cancelled by me without the need for her to bring the passport to the embassy? Is there a database for all visa were the visa can be canceled and therefore the entry in schengen can be denied?

Comment: Are you sponsoring her visit?

Comment: Which Schengen country has issued the visa? There might be slight differences in national legislation, but it is usually not possible to revoke a guarantee letter.

Comment: Issued by Italy

Comment: Yes im sponsoring the visit

Comment: And just to be clear what you have guaranteed: Have you signed a 'dichiarazione di ospitalità' for this visit? http://questure.poliziadistato.it/file/4520_4938.pdf

Comment: Yes i signed this

Comment: They of course have a database if issued visas. But even if you canceled, please let her know you have canceled it. Airport personal do not check visa validity online, so it will be the remote airport that sued get to know her visa is canceled otherwise.

Comment: Some people say a issued visa can't be cancelled by the Host (me).

Comment: Of course not, why would you think you can dispose of a visa as you please?

Comment: If she breaks the visa rules (by overstaying, working, etc.), it could affect OP's credibility and ability to sponsor other people.

Comment: @AyeshK visas can only be cancelled by a competent authority of a Schengen state.

Comment: The sword cuts both ways, the visa will be revoked and your credibility as a sponsor will be dubious going forward.  Don't plan to sponsor somebody else for a while.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A Schengen visa can be revoked.  From the [Schengen Visa Code](http://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/?uri=CELEX:02009R0810-20131018):

> A visa shall be revoked where it becomes evident that the conditions for issuing it are no longer met. A visa shall in principle be revoked by the competent authorities of the Member State which issued it.

So, as mentioned in the comments by Lily, you can inform the consulate that issued the visa that your girlfriend is now your ex-girlfriend.  They may decide to revoke the visa, but they may decide not to.

The code provides for no requirement that the visa holder be notified when a visa is revoked, beyond the visa being stamped "REVOKED"; this presumably would happen at the border when she is denied entry.  There may be some policies about notifying visa holders where possible, but this is not required by the code, so it perhaps varies from country to country.

I do not think that airlines have the ability to query the Schengen databases to confirm the validity of a traveler's visa, but I could be wrong.  In any event, if she "already went to the airport," as you mention in a comment, for her trip to Italy, it's almost certainly too late.  It's highly unlikely that there is enough time for you to inform the consulate and the consulate to make a decision to revoke the visa before she gets to the airport.

If you are worried that she might get you in trouble by doing something you have guaranteed that she wouldn't do, then maybe you should ask a separate question about that.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed explanation. Can i call the embassy and ask if they cancelled the visa? Will they tell me, or do they just only tell the visa owner?

Comment: @manabu I doubt they will tell you their decision, in the name of privacy, but I could be wrong.

Comment: but they would tell it to the visa owner right? Well they have to if she calls or?

Comment: @manabu if she calls and asks, then I suppose they would indeed tell her.  I am only uncertain about whether they would notify her on their own initiative.

Comment: (+1) The visa code does include a requirement for a notification through a standard form in article 34 (6) and a right of appeal in article 34 (7). It does not get into the details of what should happen if the person is not present but it goes beyond affixing a stamp.

Answer (score 4):

A Schengen visa can certainly be cancelled (technically revoked and/or annulled depending on the circumstances) and such a cancellation would indeed be recorded in a database… but *you* cannot cancel it. After all, you did not issue it in the first place. Also, why do you care?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/47269/discussion-on-answer-by-relaxed-cancel-a-tourist-c-visa-issued-for-all-schenge).